# Why doesn't Knuth's linear-time multiplication algorithm "count"?

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis, multiplication

The wikipedia page on multiplication algorithms mentions [an interesting one by Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Linear_time_multiplication). Basically, it involves combining fourier-transform multiplication with a precomputed table of logarithmically-sized multiplications. It runs in linear time.

The article acts like this algorithm somehow doesn't count as a "true" multiplication algorithm. More significantly, it's considered to be an open question whether multiplication can be done in even `O(n lg n)` time!

What details of this algorithm disqualify it from counting as a "true" multiplication algorithm?

My guesses are:

- Precomputing the table takes more than linear time. On the other hand, it can still be done in `n lg n` time so that would still seem to be impressive.
- Random access is somehow not allowed. But then why can other algorithms use things like hash tables and pointers?
- It somehow scales wrong as you increase a machine's word size, like if you have a 256 bit machine that does 256 bit multiplications in a single instruction then there's no point to this algorithm until you have more than 2^256 elements. On the other hand, we bother with the inverse-ackermann factor in union-find.
- The "is there a linear time multiplication algorithm?" question is secretly in terms of some weaker machine, but this only gets hinted at.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdichotomous_model

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While the algorithm you mention appears in Knuth's TAOCP, it is certainly not due to Knuth, and is more widely known as the [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm); Knuth even attributes this algorithm to them in the text. This algorithm indeed runs in linear time in the so-called *RAM machine*, in which variables are allowed to hold integers of size $O(\log n)$, where $n$ is the size of the input. The bit complexity is, however, $O(n\log n\log\log n)$, and for this model, [Fürer's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm) is faster.

The quest for fast integer multiplication algorithms in the literature has concentrated on bit complexity as the complexity measure; this is like allowing your registers to hold only one bit (or only $C$ bits for some arbitrary constant $C$). It is expected that integer multiplication takes $\Omega(n\log n)$, though it's not clear whether this should be tight, and no non-trivial lower bounds are known (so this $\Omega(n\log n)$ is just a conjecture).

For a discussion of the "correct" model for practical multiplication of large integers, check Fürer's [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.1811.pdf). His conclusion is in favor of the "practical" Schönhage–Strassen algorithm (there are two of them, and the other one has better bit complexity but performs worse in practice; Fürer addresses this issue in the paper).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't have a copy of TAOCP so all I had to go by was what was in the wiki article (I see you've already edited it to fix the issue).